# Changing which code is used in server.R based on a selected a file type in ui.R - Shiny

Tags: r, csv, checkbox, input, shiny

I am working on a Shiny App to find the best linear regression model for a data set. I want people to be able to input .txt, .xls, or .csv files. I havethis code in my ui.R :

```
 fileInput("mydata", label = h4("Please upload the .xls, .txt, or.csv file you would like included in the analysis.")),

 checkboxGroupInput("filetype", label = h4("Please select the type of data uploaded:"), choices = (".csv", ".txt", ".xls"), selected = ".xls"),

 checkboxGroupInput("header", label = h4("Does your table have a header (column names)?"), choices = ("TRUE", "FALSE"), selected = "TRUE"),
```

I believe this should allow them to browse the computer for a file, upload it, then tell me the  file type and if there are headers or not.

In my server.R, I am not sure how to tell my output to use one code if there is a .txt or .xls and another if there is a .csv. This is all I have so far:

```
  dat <- read.table(input$mydata, header=input$header) #if .xls or .txt
  dat <- read.csv(input$mydata, header=input$header) #if .csv
```

I have looked around, but can't seem to find any examples anywhere. Does anyone know what I can add to my server.R code to be able to differentiate this based on the box they chose?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use radio buttons instead of group checkboxes as the former only allows for one selection.  Group checkboxes would allow them to say that their file is both a .csv and .txt for example.  It would also mean the user can select that their file both has a header and doesn't have a header.

After you've made that change then you all you need is a basic if/then statement.  Something like...

```
header_var <- FALSE
if (input$header==1) header_var <- TRUE


if (input$filetype==1) {  # input 1 means they picked .csv
    dat <- read.csv(input$mydata, header=header_var)
}
```

... and then just include an else if for choice 2 and an else for choice 3.